# What to do about answers that include insecure key hashes?

Tags: discussion

I recently became aware of an issue when using 32 bit key hashes to receive gpg keys.  It's insecure to do so because it is now trivial to create colliding keys with the same 32 bit hash.

As a demonstration the following key hash for the R package maintainers has been duplicated by a colliding key. This can be shown by running the following command.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9

Executing: /tmp/tmp.CTf53pBy3y/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
keyserver.ubuntu.com
--recv-keys
E084DAB9
gpg: requesting key E084DAB9 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key E084DAB9: "Totally Legit Signing Key <mallory@example.org>" not changed
gpg: key E084DAB9: "Michael Rutter <marutter@gmail.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 2
gpg:              unchanged: 2
```

Note the second `Totally Legit Signing Key`.

See https://evil32.com/ for more information about the problem.

There are many questions with answers that include 32 bit keys in them, and many people are likely to copy and paste them without noticing a problem.

Is it appropriate to go through and directly edit all of those questions and answers to include the new stronger hashes?

It's very similar to this question [Editing of Insecure Code Examples](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339344/editing-of-insecure-code-examples) but I it seems like a distinct circumstance because it's a very targeted change, just substitute the new better key hash for the old bad one rather than a more general code change.

Comment: This question seems to have more nuance, but very related: [How to handle a publicly posted API key (or password, or other sensitive information)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258066/how-to-handle-a-publicly-posted-api-key-or-password-or-other-sensitive-informa)

Comment: That question seems to suggest flagging for redaction, but I don't think that's the right response here.  These are key hashes of public keys, so there's no risk by having them be public.  The risk is that such a short hash is not a good identifier for a key anymore, and if you end up trying to look up a key with them then you risk accidentally importing malicious keys that have been designed to have the same hash.

Answer (score 5):

Take a moment to reflect on the people out there who would blindly and wantonly copy a command from the Internet without validating if it's secure, safe or actually The Right Thing™ for them to do in that context.

Now...

My opinion on this is simple:  we shouldn't publish *inaccurate* information, but security precautions are **explicitly** the responsibility of the reader.  There are legitimate reasons to *want* to have to deal with insecure code or repositories (ever hear of this company called Jagex?  Their Ubuntu repository uses an insecure signing key *too* but it's still [part of their official instructions to play their headline game](https://www.runescape.com/download)), so editing that out may actually change the question or answer in unintended ways.

<sup>From another angle, if enough people in the world blindly copy every `rm -rf` command they see, we won't be *quite* as burdened with them...</sup>